# Can not load large image with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, large-data

I try to load an image with opencv that has the size 100.000 * 15.000 pixels and a file size of 4.305 kb. If i load this image with the following code:

```
   cv::Mat reallyBigImage = cv::imread("reallyBigImage.png");
```

i get the following error:

[image: Error message]

I have a pc with 32 gb ram and compile this program in 64 bit. This should be enough for an image of this size. Is it possible to load such an large image as whole to opencv?

Here is where my program breaks in assembler.
The arrow indicates the specific location. This snippet is from the memcpy.asm.

```
    CopyUp:
    cmp     r8, 128
    jbe     XmmCopySmall

    bt      __favor, __FAVOR_ENFSTRG ; check for ENFSTRG (enhanced fast strings)
    jnc     XmmCopyUp               ; If Enhanced Fast String not available, use XMM

    ; use Enhanced Fast Strings
    ; but first align the destination dst to 16 byte alignment
    mov     rax, r11                ; return original destination pointer
    mov     r11, rdi                ; save rdi in r11
    mov     rdi, rcx                ; move destination pointer to rdi
    mov     rcx, r8                 ; move length to rcx
    mov     r8, rsi                 ; save rsi in r8
    mov     rsi, r10                ; move source pointer to rsi
    -->rep     movsb                   ; copy source to destination buffer
    mov     rsi, r8                 ; restore rsi
    mov     rdi, r11                ; restore rdi
    ret
```

Comment: Do you have writing permissions in the current folder?

Comment: I can load images that are smaller than the one i try to load. And yes i can write to this folder.

Comment: I try to read a png file.

Comment: What if you read the PNG with `LodePng` and then pass the bytes to opencv via `cv::Mat`.. does that work?

Comment: LodePng gives me "decoder error 92: too many pixels, not supported" error

Comment: Was this a debug or release build?

Comment: Debug. I try Release.

Comment: In Release it is the same error: "decoder error 92: too many pixels, not supported"

Comment: @Freewister That's OK, I was just making sure you're not using a debug library in a release build, which is a fairly common mistake ending up in crashes like this. What version of  Visual C++ are you using?

Comment: I use the version 2015 v140 and compile to 64 bit

Comment: OK, and you built the OpenCV libraries yourself, using the same compiler? (If, not, where did they come from?) -- Just wanna make sure to eliminate all the typical sources of this kind of issue.

Comment: I use the prebuilt opencv library from nuget version 310.3.0 for VS2015/2017. opencv.win.native and  opencv.win.native.redist

Comment: OK, I can reproduce this with the pre-built 3.1 binaries from the OpenCV web. Testing this with 3.2 and 3.3 no longer reproduces this crash, which leads me to believe this was a bug that has since been patched. It may be a good idea to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running some local tests, this can be reproduced with OpenCV 3.1, but not with 3.2 or 3.3. That suggests it was a bug (along with the fact that you're getting an access violation in the first place).

Specifically [issue #6317](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6317).

This was fixed prior to release of OpenCV 3.2, which would match the above observations. Hence, the best option would be to upgrade your copy of OpenCV.

Comment: I updated to version 3.3 from 3.1 and i could load the image. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That image is 6 GB raw data (100,000 * 15,000 * 4 Bytes). Typically Windows limits the maximum heap size of a process much below that. But even if you increased that limit, you're going to encounter memory fragmentation (being unable to write to a single, 6GB contiguous block of memory), which OpenCV's allocator likely cannot handle.

Which is why you are getting access violation error during writing the image data to memory. It's attempting to write into a memory location it is not allowed/supposed to be writing in.

You're either going to have to split the image up into multiple ROIs/sub-images to avoid fragmentation, or write your own allocator that allocates the image in memory in smaller chunks.

Comment: But i can do this `cv::Mat image = Mat::zeros(15000, 100000, CV_8UC3);
 cv::imwrite("reallyreallyBigImage2.png", image);` I can create this image and write it to my file system.

Comment: Mat::zeros does not use Xmm extensions when setting allocated memory to 0, as cv::imread does. Writing to disk is also an entirely different process than reading into memory. Not only does OpenCV have to load the PNG data into memory, it must decode it as well, which takes up more memory.

Comment: Also, try using CV_8UC4, which takes up 33% more memory than CV_8UC3. PNG files are generally loaded with an alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

May I commend **libvips** to you if you are dealing with large images? It is available for Linux, macOS and Windows - for free, from [here](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips).

If you have a 100,000 x 15,000 `PNG` image and you want to extract a region 2000x1000 starting at a point (100,100), you would do:

```
time vips crop test.png excerpt.png 2000 1000 100 100 --vips-leak
```

**Sample Output**

```
memory: high-water mark 192.29 MB

real    0m1.771s
user    0m0.826s
sys     0m0.082s
```

As you can see, it only used 200MB of RAM and took around 1s. The `time` and `--vips-leak` were for demonstration purposes only - you can omit them normally.