# Imagemagick conversion failed for images of larger file dimension to jp2(jp2000) with AWS lambda Node.js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, aws-lambda, child-process, imagemagick-convert

AWS lambda Imagemagick convert failed for images of larger file dimension to jp2(jp2000). For images of size less then 60MB, conversion works fine, but above 60MB, I am getting 0KB file. I am using Imagemagick with child_process spawning for image conversion.

> Using AWS lambda with Node.js 6.1, 1.5GB memory and 300 second timeout

I am not able to identify why the following code is failing for larger dimension images. Is this a buffer limitation of the child_process?

```
        var fs = require('fs');
    var childproc= require('child_process');

    var child = childproc.spawn('convert', [inputfile,outputFile,]);
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(tempDest, {encoding: 'binary'});         
    child.stdout.pipe(file);
    child.on('exit', function(){ file.end();console.log("file outputed");wcallback(null);});
    child.on('error', function(err){ file.end();console.log(err);wcallback(err);});
```

I tried Imagemgick node.js wrapper package "npm Imagemagick", also. It was giving an error for the same conversion for larger file. The following is the error:

```
{
"errorMessage" : "Command failed: ",
"errorType" : "Error",
"stackTrace" : ["ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/imagemagick/imagemagick.js:92:15)", 
"emitTwo (events.js:106:13)", "ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)", 
"maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)", 
"Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)",
"emitOne (events.js:96:13)", "Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)",
"Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)"]}
```

Comment: A 60MB `JPEG` is **enormous** - what are its dimensions in pixels?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  We are having TIFF images mostly and dimension are of 9000X9000. One image details Eg: Image.114614.tif=>Image.114614.jp2 TIFF 7800x8731 7800x8731+0+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB
 78.3729MiB 113.803u 3:19.139

Comment: 9000x9000 pixels means around 500MB of RAM in Q16 ImageMagick when decompressed before you start copying or editing... 9000x9000=81Mpixels, with 2 bytes each of Red, Green and Blue, i.e. 81*6 = 486MB or 650MB with transparency.

Comment: In fact, creating a simple 9000x9000 JPEG on my machine takes 1.2GB of RAM... `/usr/bin/time -l convert -size 9000x9000 xc:gray test.jpg`

Comment: Is there any way for limiting/controling the memory usage while convertion. I have limitation like 1.5GB max memory and 5 minute max time allowable for execution in AWS lambda, so conversion should complete before 5 minutes.

Comment: See the Imagemagick policy.xml file to change limitations.

Comment: Not sure if you might be able to do better with `libvips`, see here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649982/2836621